# How to get absolute path of files outside the current working directory [java]

Tags: java, file, path, absolute-path, working-directory

I'm trying to read a file outside my current working directory using `File` and `URL` classes in Java. I know that the current working directory is 'represented' by a `.` by default.

Assuming my Java class is under `/folders/Desktop/MyClass.java`, if I want to read a file `file1.txt` in `/folders/Desktop/file1.txt`, I can do the following:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("./file1.txt");  /* or "./anotherFolder/../file1.txt", or simply "file1.txt"*/
File f = new File(url.getPath());
```

and everything works as expected.

But what should I do to read a file that is not inside the current working directory and that is not inside a subdirectory of it? For example, if the file's path is `/folders/file1.txt`? I searched everywhere, but can't find anything. I tried `../file1.txt`, `./../file1.txt` and others, but nothing works. Maybe I missed something, or maybe I haven't searched in the right places.

Comment: what's wrong with new FIle("/folders/file1.txt")?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that instruction, it works in my case.The problem occures when I want to read files that are not in subdirectories of the current working directory. In particular, a java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown when I try to create an instance of the File class.

Comment: I mean don't use resource, just new File(filename). The file can be anywhere as long as the path is correct. How can it throw NPE when the filename is not null?

Comment: Oh..It works! Thanks a lot!!! I don't know why I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give a path to the file name, then java is searching in the directory where the app is running.

## Example:

This will print `true` if the file is in the main folder of the project...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final File foo = new File("asd.txt");
        System.out.println(foo.exists());
    }
```

## EDit:

if the file if not in that folder then you can go "up" in the folder structure with the "`./`" or "`../`" operators...
or go deeper in the folders `File("/src/asd.txt")` for example is the file were inside the src folder..

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know. In fact, I haven not any type of problem with files in the current working directory and subdirectories of it. There isn't any project!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a file that is not below the current working directory you would either traverse the file system programmatically or you would get an absolute path by user input and construct the `java.io.File` object with `new File(absolutePathAsString)`. You might also consider using the newer `java.nio.file` API.